# How to get last records of each bank_id in join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter, I have a query that is not working. 
I have 3 tables which called `tbl_lead, tbl_bankdata, tbl_payment_invoice` . There is no issue with two tables joins. I am getting the issue on table `tbl_payment_invoice`.

The issue is, I am inserting the status of the payment in the `tbl_payment_invoice` table. It can be multiple statuses of the bank_id.

I have to display the last status of the user from `tbl_payment_invoice`.

tbl_payment_invoice table strcture

```
p_i_id | payment_invoice|payment_invoice_date |bank_id |payment_invoice_by
1      | 1              | 2019-09-29 20:39:12 |33      |1
2      | 2              | 2019-09-29 20:39:43 |33      |1
3      | 1              | 2019-09-29 20:40:02 |05      |1
4      | 1              | 2019-09-29 20:45:12 |20      |1
5      | 2              | 2019-09-29 20:50:38 |05      |1
6      | 2              | 2019-09-29 21:10:12 |20      |1
7      | 1              | 2019-09-29 21:15:40 |10      |1
```

My expected output is from this table is

```
p_i_id | payment_invoice|payment_invoice_date |bank_id |payment_invoice_by
2      | 2              | 2019-09-29 20:39:43 |33      |1
5      | 2              | 2019-09-29 20:50:38 |05      |1
6      | 2              | 2019-09-29 21:10:12 |20      |1
7      | 1              | 2019-09-29 21:15:40 |10      |1
```

I have to display the last records of the bank_id.

Would you help me out how to use with join?

```
public function disbursed_Leadlist(){
if($this->session->userdata['login_session']['access_role']==5){
   $or_where="tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1  AND createby='".$this->session->userdata['login_session']['id']."'"; 
}
else{
    $or_where="tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1";
}

$result = $this->db->select('*')
                  ->from('tbl_lead')
                  ->join('tbl_bankdata','tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id','LEFT')
                  ->join('tbl_payment_invoice','tbl_bankdata.bank_id=tbl_payment_invoice.bank_id','LEFT')
                  ->where($or_where)
                  ->order_by('tbl_lead.date_of_created','DESC')
                  ->get()
                  ->result();
                       // echo $this->db->last_query();
                  return $result;
  }
```

Comment: `tbl_payment_invoice` is not in your select or join list! Its only used in the inner select

Comment: Try this
**->join('(select bank_id, max(payment_invoice), max(payment_invoice_date) as dateofadded,payment_invoice from tbl_payment_invoice group by bank_id) as p_i','tbl_bankdata.bank_id=p_i.bank_id','LEFT')**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Yes, That is not in the join list. I am getting some issues in the last join. I have to fetch the records from tbl_payment_invoice

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma, give me sometime to check

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma, I tried but getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I change **max(payment_invoice)** to **max(payment_invoice)  as payment_invoice**, I think this twisting will serve..

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('tbl_lead')
        ->join('tbl_bankdata','tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id','LEFT')
        ->join('tbl_bankname','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_bankdata.b_bankname')
        ->join('(select bank_id, max(payment_invoice) as payment_invoice, max(payment_invoice_date) as dateofadded from tbl_payment_invoice group by bank_id) as p_i','tbl_bankdata.bank_id=p_i.bank_id','LEFT')
        ->where($or_where)
        ->order_by('tbl_lead.date_of_created','DESC')
        ->get()
        ->result();

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: It's not working. I am getting the same error. tbl_payment_invoice is not in my select or join the list. I need to know how can I add that

Answer (score 0):

->join('(select bank_id, max(payment_invoice), max(payment_invoice_date) as dateofadded from tbl_payment_invoice group by bank_id) as p_i','tbl_bankdata.bank_id=p_i.bank_id','LEFT').

Change the  max(payment_invoice) to payment_invoice and where query should be as p_i.payment_invoice='' because you are creating a temp table p_i from your sub query.

Comment: Give me some time. There is some power issue at my home.

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Cna you help me out?

Comment: Please share the Query using $this -> db -> last_query();

Comment: JUST Change these Lines :
if ($this -> session -> userdata['login_session']['access_role'] == 5) {
    $or_where = "tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1 AND p_i.payment_invoice=1 AND createby='" . $this -> session -> userdata['login_session']['id'] . "'";
} else {
    $or_where = "tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1 AND p_i.payment_invoice=1";
}
 
-> join('(select bank_id, max(payment_invoice) as payment_invoice, max(payment_invoice_date) as dateofadded from tbl_payment_invoice group by bank_id) as p_i', 'tbl_bankdata.bank_id=p_i.bank_id', 'LEFT')

Comment: I change the question. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You Change table name and Try this code......

```
$paidrefid = $CI->session->userdata('login_data');

    $CI->db->select('*');
    $CI->db->from('tbl_refrralcash a');
    $CI->db->join('tbl_cashback_ReqJoint b','b.cashbackID = a.id', 'left');
    $CI->db->join('tbl_cashback_request c','c.id = b.cashback_RequestID', 'left');
    $CI->db->where('a.cash_referralid',$paidrefid);
    $CI->db->where('a.paid_status','1');
    $CI->db->where('c.status','0');
    $CI->db->where('b.type','2');
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    $Reqreferal = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Is this answer for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function disbursed_Leadlist() {
    if ($this -> session -> userdata['login_session']['access_role'] == 5) {
        $or_where = "tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1  AND createby='" . $this -> session -> userdata['login_session']['id'] . "'";
    } else {
        $or_where = "tbl_bankdata.b_filestatus=1";
    }

    $result = $this -> db -> select('*,t3.payment_invoice_date') 
    -> from('tbl_lead') 
    -> join('tbl_bankdata', 'tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id', 'LEFT')
    -> join ('(select max(payment_invoice_date) as payment_invoice_date,bank_id from tbl_payment_invoice group by bank_id) t3','t3.bank_id=tbl_bankdata.bank_id','left')
    -> where($or_where) -> order_by('tbl_lead.date_of_created', 'DESC')
    -> get() -> result();
    return $result;
}
```